# Double reverse filtering in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I am facing one issue while filtering the data .

I am having three models ...

```
class Product:
   size = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Make(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product_set')

class MakeContent(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, related_name='make_set')
    published = models.BooleanField()
```

I can generate a queryset that contains all Makes and each one's related MakeContents where published = True.

```
Make.objects.filter(make_set__published=True)
```

I'd like to know if it's possible (without writing SQL directly) for me to generate a queryset that contains all Product and each one's related MakeContents where published = True.

I have tried this

```
Product.objects.filter(product_set__make_set__published=True)
```

But it's not working

Comment: I assume `name = ...` is a `ForeignKey` to `Product`, not `Make`?

Comment: The related names furthermore do not make much sense, the `related_name` is the name of the relation in reverse, so from `Product` to `Make`, by using `product_set`, you give the impression that it is a ollectiobn of `Product`s, but it is a collection of `Make`s. It is also strange that a `Product` has multiple `Make`s, and not vice-versa.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with "not working"? What error do you receive?

Comment: Related name not found

Comment: My requirement is from Product table I need to filter the data according to value in MakeContent table

Answer (score 1):

A subquery can solve the problem.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

sub_query = MakeContent.objects.filter(published=True)

Product.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Subquery(sub_query.values('make__name__pk'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Product.objects.filter(make__makecontent__published=True).distinct()
```

Filtering through ForeignKey works both forward and backwards in Django. You can use the model name in lower case for backward filtering.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Finally `.distinct()` is required to remove the multiple values produced due to SQL joins