# How to filter Double reverse filtering using Django ORM

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

Hello I am having following model structure

```
class Product:
   size = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Make(models.Model):
    make_content = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='make_set')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class MakeContent(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, related_name='make_content_set')
    published = models.BooleanField()
```

If I need to filter Product according to Make I can able to use related name

```
qs = Product.objects.filter(make_set__department = "Sample")
```

It's working fine

Now what I need is I need to filter the Product according to MakeContent

I have tried this

```
qs = Product.objects.filter(make_set__make_content_set__published = True)
```

This is not working , is there any other idea ?

Comment: not working? have you got any errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double reverse filtering in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180494/double-reverse-filtering-in-django-orm)

Comment: You have already asked the exact same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180494/double-reverse-filtering-in-django-orm/65199322#65199322. Please check the posted answers and edit/comment if not working.